# How to place data labels just above or below the data points in d3.js line chart?

Tags: d3.js

I need to show data labels just above or below the data points to avoid overlap between line and the label. If i place the data labels exactly where the coordinates of data points are it causes an overlap, any ideas?

these are my circles:

```
 demo.selectAll("dot")
                  .data(function (d) {
                      return d.values;
                  })
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("cx", function (d) {
                      return vm.xScale(d.TelecastOrder);
                  })
                  .attr("cy", function (d) {
                      return vm.yScale(d.rating);
                  })
                  .attr("r", 5)
                  .style("fill", function (d, i, j) {
                      return (d.Indicator.indexOf("S") != -1 || d.Indicator.indexOf("s") != -1) ? "white" : vm.demos[j].color;
                  })
                  .style("stroke", function (d, i, j) {
                      return vm.demos[j].color;
                  })
                  .style("display", function (d, i, j) {
                      return (vm.demos[j].visible && (d.rating != 0.0 || d.rating != 0)) ? "" : "none";
                  })
                 .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                  .attr("class", function (d, i, j) {
                      return "point-" + vm.demos[j].name + "-" + i;
                  })
                  .on("mouseover", function (d, i, j) {
                      vm.DrawTooltip(d, i, j, "");
                  })
                  .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                      vm.div.transition()
                          .duration(100)
                          .style("opacity", 0);
                  });



demo.selectAll("labels")
 .data(function (d) {
 return d.values;
 })
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .attr("dx", function (d) {
 return vm.xScale(d.TelecastOrder);
 })
.attr("dy", function (d) {
return vm.yScale(d.rating);
})
.text(function (d) { return vm.ChartingInfo.Demo != "P2+" ? d.rating.toFixed(1) : vm.GetRoundOff(d.rating) })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("fill","black");
```

Tis is my code for labels.

Comment: You can try adding `transform translate` to the label.

Comment: Where is your code? If you provide a fiddle or plunker we it would save us lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [d3fc point series component](https://d3fc.io/api/series-api.html#point), which allows you to add data-labels via the [decorate pattern](https://d3fc.io/introduction/decorate-pattern.html).

Here's what the code would look like:

```
var svgBar = fc.seriesSvgPoint()
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .crossValue(function(_, i) { return i; })
    .mainValue(function(d) { return d; })
    .decorate(function(selection) {
      selection.enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, -10)")
        .text(function(d) { return d3.format(".2f")(d); })
        .attr("fill", "black");
    });
```

Here's a [codepen with the complete example](https://codepen.io/ColinEberhardt/pen/eBjwmz).